# Inform Activity from a BroadcastReceiver ONLY if it is in the foreground

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Maybe it's easy, but I couldn't really figure this out right so far... I got a `BroadcastReceiver` waiting to get triggered by the AlarmMangager - this works fine.

Now: because the event, if it occurs, needs to refresh some elements on screen of the main Activity, I would like to send an Intent from that background BroadcastReceiver to my Activity - **but only** if it is currently in the foreground, aka active.

If it is not running or not visible, I don't care - and the last thing I want to do is start the Activity by my intent! I handle repainting of the views in my onResume() method, so I don't care at all.

Any hints on how to do that?
Thanks!

**EDIT:** my BroadcastReceiver is waiting for alarms that must be notified to the user. So, it must be there and declared in the manifest. The problem is: it will have to decide whether the mentioned Activity is currently up in front or not.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So this is almost Bino's answer, but: instead of moving the receiver into the activity, use two receivers, with different Intents. The first one is your original alarm Intent, with a receiver registered in the manifest as you already have, and then that receiver sends a second broadcast intent, which is handled by a receiver registered by the activity as Bino says.

I've done this in my own timer project, on github. Here are the [alarm receiver](http://github.com/chrisboyle/timer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/name/boyle/chris/timer/Receiver.java) and the [requery receiver](http://github.com/chrisboyle/timer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/name/boyle/chris/timer/TimerActivity.java#L131). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for an easy solution that I didn't think of yet :)

Comment: Perfect - just what I was looking for! +1 to you.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This should be taken down.  How can you have an accepted answer that has no information other than broken links?  A 404 helps noone.

Comment: @Evan Sorry, links fixed now.

Answer (score 44):

I believe that you're familiar with AlarmManager now (creating a new Alarm, register a receiver...) so I will not talk about that. Just give you a solution for your question.

Instead of registering a BroadcastReceiver in a class file and in manifest, you only create a new BroadcastReceiver in your activity, and then, register it in onResume method, and unregister it in onPause method, sth like this in your activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //do something       
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("your alarm action");
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    ...
super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
    ...
super.onPause();
}
```

The receiver will only receive the alarm intent when your activity is in foreground :)

(Sorry if my English is not clear)

Comment: Hi Bino! Thanks for your reply - I see, I have to update my question as your answer would impose a new problem...
I need the BroadcastReceiver to **always** be there, not ONLY if the Activity is running and in foreground! It's an alarm - precisely it will inform the user about a bus that he wants to catch. Now: alarms must be notified no matter what the Activity is doing. BUT: if and only if it is active and in the foreground I need to update a checkbox indicating that this specific alarm is not set any more! :-(