# How to mock getApplicationContext

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I have an application that stores app context information. The app context information  is shared between activities in MyApp class which extends Application class.

I am writing a unit test for my activity, and I want to check that when user clicks a button in the activity, an application state will change. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View pView) {
    ((MyApp)getApplicationContext()).setNewState();
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to mock that application context. I am using *ActivityUnitTestCase* as a test case base. When I call *setApplication*, it changes the value of *mApplication* member of *Activity* class, but not application context. I've tried *setActivityContext* also, but it seems wrong (it is not app context but activity context) and it fires assert inside *startActivity*).

So the question is - how to mock *getApplicationContext()*?

Comment: I've came up with idea of replacing _getApplicationContext()_ with _getApplication()_. Now I can mock _Application_ object and  use _setApplication()_. It is kinda workaround. However, I don't get the difference between those methods. And the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545) related to that is not answered.

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64678091/4797289

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since the method `getApplicationContext` is inside the class that you're extending it becomes somewhat problematic. There are a couple of problems to consider:

- You really can't mock a class that is under test, which is one of the many drawbacks with object inheritance (i.e. subclassing).
- The other problem is that [`ApplicationContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) is a [singleton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29), which makes it all more evil to test since you can't easily mock out a global state that is programmed to be irreplaceable.

What you can do in this situation is to prefer *[object composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)*. So in order to make your `Activity` testable you need to split up the logic a little. Lets say that your `Activity` is called `MyActivity`. It needs to be *composed* of a logic component (or class), lets name it `MyActivityLogic`. Here is a simple class-diagram figure:

[image: MyActivity and MyActivityLogic UML diagram from yUml]

To solve the singleton problem, we let the logic be "injected" with an application context, so it can be tested with a mock. We then only need to test that the `MyActivity` object has put the correct application context into `MyActivityLogic`. How we basically solve both problems is through [another layer of abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) (paraphrased from Butler Lampson). The new layer we add in this case is the activity logic moved outside of the activity object.

For the sake of your example the classes need to look sort-of like this:

```
public final class MyActivityLogic {

    private MyApp mMyApp;

    public MyActivityLogic(MyApp pMyApp) {
        mMyApp = pMyApp;
    }

    public MyApp getMyApp() {
        return mMyApp;
    }

    public void onClick(View pView) {
        getMyApp().setNewState();
    }
}

public final class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // The activity logic is in mLogic
    private final MyActivityLogic mLogic;

    // Logic is created in constructor
    public MyActivity() {
        super(); 
        mLogic = new MyActivityLogic(
            (MyApp) getApplicationContext());
    }

    // Getter, you could make a setter as well, but I leave
    // that as an exercise for you
    public MyActivityLogic getMyActivityLogic() {
        return mLogic;
    }

    // The method to be tested
    public void onClick(View pView) {
        mLogic.onClick(pView);
    }

    // Surely you have other code here...

}
```

It should all look something like this:
[image: classes with methods made in yUml]

To test `MyActivityLogic` you will only need a simple jUnit `TestCase` instead of the `ActivityUnitTestCase` (since it isn't an Activity), and you can mock your application context using your mocking framework of choice (since *handrolling* your own mocks is a bit of a drag). Example uses [Mockito](http://mockito.org/):

```
MyActivityLogic mLogic; // The CUT, Component Under Test
MyApplication mMyApplication; // Will be mocked

protected void setUp() {
    // Create the mock using mockito.
      mMyApplication = mock(MyApplication.class);
    // "Inject" the mock into the CUT
      mLogic = new MyActivityLogic(mMyApplication);
}

public void testOnClickShouldSetNewStateOnAppContext() {
    // Test composed of the three A's        
    // ARRANGE: Most stuff is already done in setUp

    // ACT: Do the test by calling the logic
    mLogic.onClick(null);

    // ASSERT: Make sure the application.setNewState is called
    verify(mMyApplication).setNewState();
}
```

To test the `MyActivity` you use `ActivityUnitTestCase` as usual, we only need to make sure that it creates a `MyActivityLogic` with the correct `ApplicationContext`. Sketchy test code example that does all this:

```
// ARRANGE:
MyActivity vMyActivity = getActivity();
MyApp expectedAppContext = vMyActivity.getApplicationContext();

// ACT: 
// No need to "act" much since MyActivityLogic object is created in the 
// constructor of the activity
MyActivityLogic vLogic = vMyActivity.getMyActivityLogic();

// ASSERT: Make sure the same ApplicationContext singleton is inside
// the MyActivityLogic object
MyApp actualAppContext = vLogic.getMyApp();
assertSame(expectedAppContext, actualAppContext);
```

Hope it all makes sense to you and helps you out.

Comment: Great answer. Indeed your introducing MVP pattern for android :)

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Your keeping of OO theory is impressive.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not exactly the same, but similar. Here is what worked for me.

Firstly, at a class level for the test

```
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CustomApp.class, AppUtils.class})
public class CustomClientTest {

    @Mock
    Context mockContext;

    @Mock
    MainActivity mainActivityMock;
```

then the setup()

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(CustomApp.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(AppUtils.class);
    when(CustomApp.getAppContext()).thenReturn(mockContext);
    when(webViewMock.getContext()).thenReturn(mainActivityMock);
}
```

and finally in the test itself

```
@Test
public void testShouldDoMyMethodRight() {
    // true tests
    assertTrue(customClient.shouldDoMethod(webViewMock, Constants.HAPPY_PATH));
    assertTrue(customClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webViewMock, Constants.SPECIAL_PATH));
}
```