# Read shared preference when context is changed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a DialogView which stores settings in shared preferences. It is located in package `A` and i have another activity which is located in package `B`, which should be able to read these preferences.

So I created a wrapper class, which takes context and shared preference name and retrive these settings. When shared preferences are set at the first time everything works great, but when I change  it, I got the same result, which was set at first time.

Problem is I save preference in one process and need to be able to read them in another.

So it seems like `Context` has changed and I am not able to retrive new context. What should I do to get up to-date shared preference?

Thank you on advance.

Please take a look at my wrapper class

```
public class PhotoAppWidgetSettingsProxy extends Proxy {

    private final static String PREFERENCES_NAME = PhotoAppWidgetSettingsProxy.class.getName();
    private final static int PREFERENCES_MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    private Context mCtx = null;
    private SharedPreferences pref = null;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;


    public PhotoAppWidgetSettingsProxy(String name, Context context) {
        super(name, context);       
        mCtx = context;
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, PREFERENCES_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }


    private final static String FRAME = "FRAME";

    /**
     * Sets selected frame mode 
     * @param frame id
     */
    public void setFrameMode(int frameId){
        editor.putInt(FRAME, frameId);

        Log.d(PREFERENCES_NAME, "SET MODE="+frameId);
        boolean success = editor.commit();
        Log.d(PREFERENCES_NAME, "SET MODE="+success);
    }
    /**
     * Gets selected frame mode 
     * @return frame id
     */
    public int getFrameMode(){
        Log.d(PREFERENCES_NAME, "GET MODE="+pref.getInt(FRAME, 0));
        return pref.getInt(FRAME, 0);
    }
```

SOLVED:

```
private final static int PREFERENCES_MODE = Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS;
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Context.. may be you are not setting the values properly

Comment: I do set values properly. Commit returns true. And when I try to get these preference from same package I got up-to-date values. Please take a look at my wrapper class in the questions. Just attached it.

Comment: What do you mean by "packages" ? Do you mean two different apps ?

Comment: just two different Java packages.

Comment: Are you reading the settings from the same process ?

Comment: I'm not sure, need to investigate this. Just got sources today morning. And if I do read settings from different process is there any way to get up-to-date shared preferences?

Comment: I think i set settings in one process and trying to read them in another, could that be an issue?

Comment: It is definetly two seperate processes. Please help me with that.

Comment: @unresolved_external if the query is resolved please mark it answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private final static int PREFERENCES_MODE = Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS;
```

Answer (score 2):

When accessing shared preferences/values, I have found it useful to write a CustomApplication class extending Application. I can place any necessary fields/methods in there, and easily acquire them from any of the other Android classes by using:

```
CustomApplication app = (CustomApplication) getApplication(); 
int x = app.getX();
```

Does that help you at all?

Comment: I just read from this site that you should never call getApplication() excplicitly :)

Comment: That's interesting! Can you link me to that?

Comment: This is the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext , but I missplaced getApplication and getApplicationContext(). My bad.

Comment: Thanks! Did my comment help you?

Comment: actually, no ;) But I figured it out by meself, see my question above if you are interested in it. And thanks for you replies :)