# Obtain application from ReceiverRestrictedContext as if getApplication was used (not getApplicationContext)

Tags: android, android-context

I have a BroadcastReceiver that has to get and modify some data from the application class. This data is retrieved and modified in some activities too.

I read this post:

[getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)

And, as it says, getApplication doesn't always return the same object as getApplicationContext. In my case, if I set an integer in my BroadcastReceiver using getApplicationContext and then I check its value in my activity (using getApplication) it's always 0 (default value).

I tried using getApplicationContext in both places, but the objects returned aren't the same. Is there any way to get the same object in BroadcastReceiver as I get in my activity using getApplication? Should I use SharedPreferences instead?

Here's an example:

BroadcastReceiver:

```
MyApp app = (MyApp)context.getApplicationContext();
app.setNumPA(10);
```

Activity:

```
MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
Log.d("MyActivity", "Num PA: "+app.getNumPA());
```

In my activity the log always shows "Num PA: 0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definately use some persistent storage, for example `SharedPreferences`.

A reason behind this - your application instance can be killed by Android OS almost at any time (while your app in background). So, you can't rely on your variables, even `static`. You should save your state in persistent storage instead.