# Firebase Android Authentication failed: expired_token (Auth token is expired)

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I encounter an issue with Android Firebase Auth using `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1`.

1 hour after authentication with Firebase (Google or Facebook), I get the following error:

`W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: expired_token (Auth token is expired)`

Why does Firebase token expire after 1 hour and how to extend this expiration period?

**UPDATE**

I still encounter this issue, Firebase token expires after 1 hour. Now I get the following message:
`W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: invalid_token (Invalid claim 'kid' in auth header.)`

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello, I'm using firebase-auth:9.0.2 and I've the same problem. Have you found a solution, please?

Comment: Have you found a solution to it? I am still facing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If we use default Auth providers like (Google, Facebook, Email..), updating "SHA-1 key" of your Application in firebase console would fix the token expiry issue.

In this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=sl#!topic/firebase-talk/CjE9ra_nwrw) a Google developer shared a guide to solve this problem.

Guide: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94LePkXiqa6SXVFd3N1NzJHX1E/view

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement [`FirebaseInstanceIdService`](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java) to get refresh token.

**Access the registration token**:

You can access the token's value by extending [**FirebaseInstanceIdService**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService). Make sure you have added the service to your [manifest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), then call `getToken` in the context of `onTokenRefresh`, and log the value as shown:

```
    @Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

> The **onTokenRefreshcallback** fires whenever a new token is generated, so
>   calling `getToken` in its context ensures that you are accessing a
>   current, available registration token. `FirebaseInstanceID.getToken()`
>   returns null if the token has not yet been generated.

**Code:**

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

I hope its helps you.

Comment: Thank you @pRaNaY, I'll try that. Why isn't this mentioned in Firebase Authentication docs? The old Firebase console allowed to set token expiration period manually, now I can't find this option anymore.

Comment: token described here is device registration token for FCM - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: This is not the auth token. This is for the fcm token. Both are totally different things!

Answer (score 0):

The new maximum life time for Firebase Tokens is 1 hour - I read it in the docs earlier today.

As for *Invalid claim 'kid' in auth header.*, I get exactly 2 search results on Google for that (: No documentation related to *kid* in Firebase docs. I guess we will have to wait for answers from Google (or switch back to the old version of Firebase if possible).

Answer (score 0):

check if the last user is null or expired

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
        if (account == null || account.isExpired()) {
            System.out.println("AccountGoogle: null");
            GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso);
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            fragment.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

        }
```