# How to launch FCM ID Service only after a particular activity is triggered?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Assume I have a `LoginActivity` where user can either register or login with existing credentials. I don't want `FirebaseInstanceIdService` to generate a token, unless user is logged in and `MainActivity` of the application is launched.

Thank you

Comment: Just call the `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`. Or wherever in the Activity you think you'll need it.

Comment: According to logs, my `FirebaseInstanceIdService` implementation generates token on application startup. Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: Sorry. I'm a bit confused. Are you referring to `FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh()`?

Comment: Yeah, apologies for not pointing that out

Comment: Hmm. `onTokenRefresh()` will always fire when there is in need of a new InstanceId (the previous token is invalidated). Check out the [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID) for what triggers this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot block `FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh()` from being called until the user is logged in.

What you could do in your use case is:

- In `FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh()` ignore the event if the user is not logged-in
- When the user log-in check `FirebaseInstanceId.getToken()` and if `!= null` call `onTokenRefresh()` (or directly your logic) manually.

In this way you can process the token when the user is logged-in, and if the token is not available (or is rotated) you will receive the `onTokenRefresh()` event later.

**Update (July 3 2017)**: in the comments a reader reminded that `FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh()` could be called after the user log in.

This is right. When the user log in, `getToken()` could still return `null` if `onTokenRefresh()` has not been called earlier.

You need to hadle this case in your app. Most likely the user can use the app anyway, but you cannot send a push notification until you received the token.

When `onTokenRefresh()` is finally called, if the user log in before, than you can associate the token the user.

Comment: What if FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh() is called after user log in it is an async call?

Comment: That can happen and you need to handle the case in your app. Most likely the user can use the app anyway, but you cannot send a push notification until you received the token. Then when you receive the token you can associate it to the user that log in before. (I updated the answer too)

Comment: that nice but I think we need to delete the instance and recall the `getInstance()` method after login in case if its called before by firebase to get new token from newly generated Instance .

Comment: it should not be required

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but that is not possible. `FirebaseInstanceIdService` call automatically on application startup and generate a `Token`. Keep in mind that its related with application `Instance`. Not with the one particular user. If you are trying to save `Token` with one particular user (i.e when user logged in then you will save that `token` in server db for push notification of that user).If you are doing this a bug you will faced in future is that if *Two* user share one application `Instance` then push notification may be pushed to wrong user ..
Hope you get my point.

Comment: Hi Usmal. How to solve this problem? Maybe removing token association from logged out user on my server, and adding it to newly logged in user... what do you think about?

Comment: @Alessandro yes i had a problem ..i did what you mention

Comment: @usmanlqbal i got one issue..i want to get fcm id at splash screen..but the issue is that my another api call first and then i am getting fcm id..what is the issue

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan you need to do your api call in FCMservice method `onTokenRefresh()`

Answer (score 0):

I am maintaining one flag in shared pref which indicates whether gcm token sent to server or not. In Splash screen every time I am calling one method sendDevicetokenToServer. This method checks if user id is not empty and gcm send status then send token to server.

```
   public static void  sendRegistrationToServer(final Context context) {

    if(Common.getBooleanPerf(context,Constants.isTokenSentToServer,false) ||
            Common.getStringPref(context,Constants.userId,"").isEmpty()){

        return;
    }

    String token =  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    String userId = Common.getUserId(context);
    if(!userId.isEmpty()) {
        HashMap<String, Object> reqJson = new HashMap<>();
        reqJson.put("deviceToken", token);
        ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<JsonElement> call = apiService.updateDeviceToken(reqJson,Common.getUserId(context),Common.getAccessToken(context));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> serverResponse) {

                try {
                    JsonElement jsonElement = serverResponse.body();
                    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonElement.toString());
                    if(context == null ){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(response.getString(Constants.statusCode).equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.responseStatusSuccess)) {

                        Common.saveBooleanPref(context,Constants.isTokenSentToServer,true);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable throwable) {

                Log.d("", "RetroFit2.0 :getAppVersion: " + "eroorrrrrrrrrrrr");
                Log.e("eroooooooorr", throwable.toString());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

In MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class

```
 @Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    Common.saveBooleanPref(this,Constants.isTokenSentToServer,false);
    Common.sendRegistrationToServer(this);

}
```