# APNS with Firebase version 3

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've set up Firebase to send push notifications to users of my app. However, I'm not sure what's best practice regarding user-to-user communication, such as chat clients. Should I get the device token at each startup of the app and use that for sending, or should I create a new topic for each "chatroom" that both parties are required to subscribe to? For instance when accepting a chat request.

If the first option is the best, how does this work? If the device is assigned a new token upon app startup, how can I be sure a given ID points to a specific device? The whole concept seems fragile - but could someone guide me to the most efficient solution?

**I'm only looking to send chat messages / chat invites with push**

Comment: Chatting is best to be handled using Socket Programming Technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size and the privacy of the chatroom you can choose between using:

- **topics** made for big groups, and without protections on joining / leaving
- **device tokens** that you need to store in your server implementation.
  On the plus side they allow you to control the who is receiving the
  messages, and to send messages to individual device.

The device token does not change every startup.
It is created when the application is launched for the first time, and can be updated in special cases. When the token change (again, this is rare) the `FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh()` callback is called.

In a generic chat application you might want to:

1. first authenticate the user with your login system
2. upload to your server the mapping user-id > device-token
3. send messages to the users via the FCM server-side APIs.

---

**Update to address one of the comments:**

1. The server-side API allows to send the same message to multiple tokens in the same HTTP request. See `registration_ids` in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json
2. You should not use the server-side API in the client, because that would require you to add the API-KEY in the application which is a security issue (people could decompile the app and read the key)
3. The storage structure is up to you. For user-id > multiple-device-tokens a dictionary could work.
4. If the token are non reusable. So it's safe to send messages to expired token.
5. Token generation requires internet connectivity, so it could take some time.
6. To handle token after user registration see this question:
   [How to launch FCM ID Service only after a particular activity is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517254/how-to-launch-fcm-id-service-only-after-a-particular-activity-is-triggered/37533266#37533266)

Comment: I see, that clears some confusion that the device token doesn't change - but is rather generated once during startup. Currently I got a node `users/<userid>` and I could store the token there. For instance like `users/<userid>/device_token`

Comment: that sounds good. just keep in mind that a userid can have multiple devices (and so multiple tokens). PS: if this covers your question please accept the answer to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Can I send a single notification to multiple tokens using the iOS SDK? If so, I should store the tokens as a dictionary? If the token changes and you fail to update your database accordingly, is it dangerous to send a private notification to that token? Or is a unique, non-reusable key? Is this token generated instantly? Or does it rely on a network connection or similar? Because I'm not completely sure how to handle the database update logic, if the token may be generated both before and after initial user registration. Is it safe to use the token as a key regarding permitted characters?

Comment: Could you explain number 2 in more depth please?

Comment: sure: to send messages programmatically you need to use the server-side API. This API requires your server to authenticate with an API-KEY that can be considered the "password" needed send messages. You should use this api, and this api-key / password, only in your cloud server.
If you try to use the server-side api from the client you would need to write the password in clear in the app, and everybody could find it using an application decompiler.

Comment: I think I understand. So you don't send the actual notification from the app, but rather tell the server to do it?

Comment: yes correct: the app need to tell the your server to send the notification.
In this way you can protect the API-KEY, and also apply more control on who is sending messages, the content of the message, and the target of the message.

Comment: I see. Does Google offer such a server or do I need to implement a 3rd party solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113493/discussion-between-diego-giorgini-and-erik).