# onTokenRefresh not getting called in signed APK, if previous version of app installed doesn't have FCM implemented

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM in version 6 of my Android application. `onTokenRefresh()`  is getting called if my app is not previously installed. But when my app with a previous version (***which did not have FCM implemeted***) is already installed and I update it with version 6, then the `onTokenRefresh()` is not getting called.

Do I need to uninstall the previous app version from Play Store and then install new version?

Answer (score 2):

I think that should still be the intended behavior. `onTokenRefresh()` will be called the **first time** the app is installed. Not every time it's updated. So maybe, you could manually force the `onTokenRefresh()` like what is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579912/4625829):

> If you would like to manually force the `onTokenRefresh()`, you can create an IntentService and delete the token instance. Then, when you call getToken, the `onTokenRefresh()` method will be called again.

Comment: Yes, I think onTokenRefresh() not getting called when app is updated :(

Comment: A token is generated when your first start an app that uses FCM. If you start your service later, you may have missed the `onTokenRefresh()` call. But the solution is simple: call `FirebaseInstanceID.getToken()` as described in the section [Retrieve the current registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token) and handle the token how you'd normally do it in `onTokenRefresh()`. If the token hasn't been generated yet, it'll return `null`. But in that case, your `onTokenRefresh()` will be called once the token is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs :) @FrankvanPuffelen