# FCM token is refresh after update app. Why?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

can you explain me pls, why when  i update my xamarin app , fcm token refreshed, it is not convenient and i need to synchronize it again with the server, I read in the documentation that the fcm token should not have been refreshed when the app is updated 
I use this FCM plugin, and i set property"resetToken" false
https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin

[Is FCM token refreshed on app update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330078/is-fcm-token-refreshed-on-app-update)

```
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, new NotificationUserCategory[]
        {
        new NotificationUserCategory("message",new List<NotificationUserAction> {
            new NotificationUserAction("Reply","Reply",NotificationActionType.Foreground),
            new NotificationUserAction("Forward","Forward",NotificationActionType.Foreground)

        }),
        new NotificationUserCategory("request",new List<NotificationUserAction> {
            new NotificationUserAction("Accept","Accept",NotificationActionType.Default,"check"),
            new NotificationUserAction("Reject","Reject",NotificationActionType.Default,"cancel")
        })

        }, false);
```

Comment: do you mean token regenerating? How do you know that updated app has different token than before. How do you update app?

Comment: When I update the app from the play market, I stop receiving notifications and my app have event OnTokenRefresh, I can see it in the log file, I raise the app version, after use Archive..., sign Ad-hoc, then upload on play market

Comment: Did you have the following opreations?1.The app deletes Instance ID  2.The app is restored on a new device  3. The user uninstalls/reinstall the app  4.The user clears app data. If you have these operation, The registration token may change.

Comment: No, I can somehow see if my Instance ID was removed after update, may be use log?

Comment: You could check the log