# How to create unique token, in every users firebase android?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, token

I want to generate and store token everytime users login. I tried for my code below, but it always generate same token when I login with another account.

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        AlertDialog.dismiss();
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (password.length() < 6) {
                                new SweetAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                                        .setTitleText("Oops...")
                                        .setContentText("Enter minimum 6 charachters !! ")
                                        .show();
                            } else {
                                passwordInput.setText("");
                                new SweetAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                                        .setTitleText("Oops...")
                                        .setContentText("Authentication failed !!")
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } else {



                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            FirebaseUser users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/"+ users.getUid());
                            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                            Log.e("tokenid",""+token);
                            mDatabase.child("token_id").setValue(token);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

please help, thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the following line of code:

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

You are getting the Firebase Instance ID token, which is also known as `FCM token`, on the client side. You need to know that in Firebase there two different tokens:

1. A FCM Token/Instance ID token that identifies an installation of a specific application on a specific user device. It doesn't identify in any way a particular user.
2. An Auth ID token identifies a specific user of a specific application. It doesn't identify in any way a particular device.

The two tokens are quite different and serve different purposes. Please see the official documentation for Android regarding on how to [retrieve ID tokens on clients](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients).

The identity of the user is remembered indefinitely (or until you sign out). But their credentials (or rather, whether their token is still valid) are re-checked every hour.

Comment: I'm using for your code it work nice and generate different token, but every time im login with the same account. It also generate different token

Comment: Good to hear that it worked! :) Yes, the identity of the user is remembered indefinitely (or until you sign out). But their credentials (or rather, whether their token is still valid) are re-checked every hour.

Comment: 1 more question, how to delete the token, when users loging out?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/googlearchive/firebase-token-generator-node/issues/3

Comment: Sir, after long process I'm realize. This is not fcm token. I want to generate FCM Token

Comment: @yehezkielyehezkiel In this case, you should make your own attempt and ask another question if something else comes up.

Answer (score 0):

FCM generates a registration token for the client app instance, hence It may happen that you'll get the same token for different users in your app. You can use forceRefresh to generate a new token every time. Register new token everytime user logins to any device and save it in DB and update with a new token on new login this way you will have a new token for each user on every login (If this fits your requirement)

Here is a good answer to understand how it works [Firebase FCM force onTokenRefresh() to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454501/firebase-fcm-force-ontokenrefresh-to-be-called)

Answer (score -1):

Use `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

You can read more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid).

[java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) - and here =)

Comment: I want to store token, not uid sir..
please read the question carefully

Comment: Oh. Got it. Sorry. Let me think a little bit