# ActiveAndroid- unable to create Tables when initialized explicitly

Tags: android, activeandroid

In my application rather than following the regular hierarchy of the ActiveAndorid,

I'm explicitly calling with the `.initialize()` method by passing the `getApplicationContext`.

However, the `TableInfo` returned doesnt have any Tables from the model class that I'm creating.

I tried debug their code and it seems an issue with the classloader they are using. 
My code is:

```
ActiveAndroid.initialize(getApplicationContext());
TestModel model=new TestModel();
model.value="hello";
model.save();
```

Comment: ActiveAndroid.initialize() doesn’t return anything (void). What exactly is your problem? Did you read and follow the documentation? https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: I'm not expecting it to return anything, but the method internally scans the code and creates the table structure as per the annotations, which it is not.

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: no i'm not using proguard

Answer (score 0):

You should not use getApplicationContext. It might not return the context of your application. The naming of getApplicationContext is misleading.

More info here: [getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)