# What is context in android?

Tags: android

Why we really need to pass context in some elements and what is the difference between `getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, `MainActivity.this` ?

Comment: There are many questions here that have the answer you are looking for. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) for the exact same question. Also have a look at answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)

Answer (score 1):

This was asked and answered several times.

Please see this question: [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3572463/1820695) and the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572553/1820695

For differences between various `Context` accessor methods (`getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, `this` in `Activity`, etc.) see this question: [Android - what's the difference between the various methods to get a Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1026973/1820695)

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question itself, this ought to be a comment.

Comment: @Sam you're most likely right given your rep - it just seemed like a place to list available answers, verified by myself. still, I'll keep that in mind in the future, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: "This was asked and answered several times." should be a comment and a close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If we go by the documentation

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This
>   is an abstract    class whose implementation is provided by the
>   Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and
>   classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as
>   launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

In Simple words its the context of current state of the application/object. It lets newly created objects understand what has been going on. Typically you call it to get information regarding another part of your program (activity, package/application)

For the difference between getApplicationContext() and getBaseContext() please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-g)