# Why am I getting "The method getContext() is undefined for the type MainActivity"?

Tags: java, android

My MainActivity extends activity and I use `getContext()` in another class that has a instance of MainActivity passed in and it works fine there, my code:

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.nowview, parent, false);
```

Class constructor:

```
public PictureCard(String url, String title, int index,
                                             int pos, MainActivity parent)
{
    this.parent = parent;
    // ...
}
```

How I call the class

```
Card newCard = new PictureCard(links.get(index) , titles.get(index),
                                                  index, position, parent);
```

(Parent is passed in as this from the MainActivity class)

Comment: it will be helpful if you post the method signature and method call of that class

Comment: ok updated, sorry for the lack of detail

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getContext()`?

These links might help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

[getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)

[Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-g)

Comment: Same issue "The method getActivityContext() is undefined for the type MainActivity"

Comment: all forms of getcontext result in some kind of error, weird this is i run the same code in another class with the same pass in and declaration of parent, and it works?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing MainActivity you can pass context as parameter lik this

```
public PictureCard(String url, String title, int index, int pos, Context parent)
```

and call like

```
Card newCard = new PictureCard(links.get(index) , titles.get(index), index, position, MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: I think i will try that, I am just baffled to why what I am doing is working in one class and not another

Answer (score 0):

If `MainActivty` extends `Activty`, then just use `parent` as the context:

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent)
                        .inflate(R.layout.nowview, parent, false);
```

Also, I suspect that you're passing the wrong instance here:

```
Card newCard = new PictureCard(links.get(index) , titles.get(index),
                                              index, position, parent);
                                                               ^^^^^^
```

it should be `this`, or `MainActivty.this` if it's within an inner class.

Comment: then I get "The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, MainActivity, boolean)"

Comment: sorry I realized I misspoke I call this class from a class that is called by MainActivity, but still why would eclipse give me this error, I created the var correctly