# Is my custom Application object instantiated before any of my other code is executed?

Tags: android, android-context

In my `Application` subclass, I save a static reference to `Context`, so that I don't have to pass contexts around in the rest of my code. I just use `MyApplication.getAppContext()` whenever I need the application `Context`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Is this safe? Is there a possible scenario where `MyApplication.getAppContext()` returns `null`?

Comment: Why are you placing that getter to get the get the application `context`? Check this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5018545/119895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it with following statement in mind, you are safe to go!

> onCreate()
>   Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

And check following post as well.

[Using Application context everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere?rq=1)

Comment: Ok, great! So it seems that unless I call `MyApplication.getAppContext()` from `MyApplication`'s constructor or static initializer, I'm fine.

Answer (score 2):

A static initializer may call the method at class load time before any object instances are created. Also, a class constructor may call the method before the onCreate method has been called, so yes, the method may return null.