# Is there any difference between Activityname.this() & this?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, forceclose

Is there any difference between `Activityname.this()` & `this` in Android?

I am trying to open an activity from same activity with button in dialog box? I am using `getApplicationContext()` in intent. In some mobiles it works, but in others it force closes?

Between **ActivityName.this** and **this** which one I should use & why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any difference between Activityname.this() & this in Android ?

This depends on where you are calling it from. If you are inside the `Activity`, not inside of a listener or inner class like in `onCreate` then no. They both refer to the `Activity context`.

If you are say inside of an `onClickListener` then yes. `this` refers to the `listener` and you need to use `ActivityName.this` or something like

```
someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent i = (v.getContext(), NextActivity.class);   use the button context which will be the same as the activity context
        startActivity(i);
     }
});
```

This will be the same as when using a `Dialog` or `AlertDialog`, you will want to use `ActivityName.this`

[This is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context) that talks about the difference of `Context`s but there's a better one I will see if I can find

[A great Context explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955)

**Edit for more completeness**

AFAIK, `getApplicationContext()` or `ActivityName.this` is fine for `Toasts`. The [example in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView) uses `getApplicationContext()`. But the [Toast Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#Toast(android.content.Context)) says

> Parameters
>   context The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.

So there may be certain instances where one is better but I have always used `Activity Context` and I guess I will until I am corrected on this.

Comment: can i use MainActivity.this() instead of getApplicationContext() every where in same activity ,if i am in same MainActivity ?

Comment: Yes, and for most things it will be better than using `getApplicationContext()`. I can't find the answer but CommonsWare has a good explanation on the differences. `Context` can be confusing when you first start with Android

Comment: I found it and added it to my answer

Comment: I agree...that guy normally does a decent job. Like he knows a thing or two or something ;)

Comment: one more question.
will replacing getApplicationContext() with MainActivity.this() make any effect to Toasts ?
Becuase google recommends to use getApplicationContext() in Toast ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37056/discussion-between-shruti-and-codemagic)

Answer (score 1):

no `MyActivity.this` is the same thing as just using `this` when you are in the activity itself and not something like a runnable where `this` would refer to the runnable and not the context

you should always use `this` or `getActivity()` if in a fragment and never use `getApplicationContext()`

check here for why you shouldn't use `getApplicationContext()`

[getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)

Comment: can i use MainActivity.this() instead of getApplicationContext() every where in same activity ,if i am in same MainActivity ?

Comment: yes you certainly can and that would be the preferred way to get context