# Can one activity have many contexts?

Tags: android, class, android-context

Something I am not sure if I got it right or not, can one class let say which extends activity have more than one context or not ? If yes, how?

Comment: No.[See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704228/is-there-any-difference-between-activityname-this-this/18704355#18704355) and the linked answer in it for a better understanding. There is `Application Context` but it isn't associated with the `Activity`. See the link for a better understanding of the differences.

Comment: No.  `Activity` extends `Context`.  Please see the Activity documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A class that extends `Context` **is a** `context`, and it can only be one, but it may hold references to other contexts as well, for example, by retrieving the application context by calling [`getApplicationContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29).