# Context inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm currently attempting to put my authorisation code for an app into an external class, so I'm not repeating myself whenever it is required and to tidy up the code.

The problem that I am having is that I can't seem to access my Session variables from inside the AsyncTask. I would love to try and figure it out myself to better understand the situation, but another problem is that there is no error in [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file), so I have no idea what's going wrong! My authorise class is below:

```
public class AuthoriseMe extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    public Context context;

    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

    Log.i(TAG, "I GOT HERE");
    SessionManager session = new SessionManager(context);
    Log.i(TAG, "I GOT PAST HERE");

        String authorized = "";
        HashMap<String, String> app = session.getAPPDetails();
        String appid = app.get(SessionManager.KEY_APPID);
        String secret = app.get(SessionManager.KEY_SECRET);
    }
}
```

The code I'm using to start the AsyncTask is below, where another class is calling authoriseMe();

```
public void authoriseMe() {
    AuthoriseMe authorise = new AuthoriseMe();
    authorise.execute();
}
```

authoriseMe() is being called as I have logged the process, but it looks like the line "SessionManager session = new SessionManager(context);" is where the problem is happening, as if I take that line out I get 'I GOT PAST HERE' in my logical.

My constructor for the SessionManager looks like this:

```
// Constructor
public SessionManager(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}
```

From what I can see it looks like an issue with context within the asyncTask. Is there any way around this? Has anyone any previous experience of this?

Comment: where do you say to your authorise which context should use? It looks like you just declared context in your class but never assing a value to it?

Comment: where is context initialized in asynctask?

Comment: That's sort of my question, is there a context inside an external asynctask? Normally I would assign it in the class that contains the asynctask, but this is seperate from that flow

Comment: you should go with given answer bellow, activities have context so you can pass that.

Comment: Just a side note - If your context is an activity context, make sure to use a WeakReference<Context>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see you initialize your `context` memeber. Just add proper constructor:

```
public AuthoriseMe(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

and then instead of

```
AuthoriseMe authorise = new AuthoriseMe();
```

do

```
AuthoriseMe authorise = new AuthoriseMe(context);
```

and you are done. Alternatively you can just obtain the context by calling `getApplication()` or `getApplicationContext()` (be sure to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)), which should be sufficient for most cases.

Comment: Thank you kindly sir! Still trying to get my head around context, especially with the background thread.

Comment: It will cause memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, the problem is simply that you never initialize nor set your `context` variable explicitly, thus its value is the one it is *implicitly* initialized to.
When you write:

```
public class AuthoriseMe extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
    public Context context;
    ...
```

this is equivalent to:

```
public class AuthoriseMe extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
    public Context context = null;
    ...
```

(the null affectation happens when you create a new AuthoriseMe object, just before its constructor is executed)
So you see that in your current code it'll remain `null`, hence your problems.

More importantly though, keep in mind that

1. an Android `Context` is highly stateful *and* has a lifetime, so

   - you want to avoid leaking them as much as possible (memory-wise)
   - if you try to use a `Context` which lifetime has already ended (i.e. has been destroyed), you'll most likely run into troubles
2. an `AsyncTask` lifetime is *independent* of any `Activity` or other `Context` lifetime, i.e. here your `AuthorizeMe` task may very well be running and trying to do things while the `Context` it holds has already been destroyed (which again will lead to problems...), so

   - you should avoid *holding* a reference to a `Context` in an `AsyncTask`

So in your case, what you could do is to simply keep a reference to the `SharedPreferences` in your `SessionManager` and not retain any `Context` reference as member variables (would be my preference), or you can also make sure that the `Context` you hold a reference to is the application context (this one's lifetime is the same as the app itself so is "not a problem" to leak).

Here's what the first solution would look like:

```
public static class AuthoriseMe extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
    private final SessionManager mSessionManager;

    public AuthoriseMe(Context context) {
        this.mSessionManager = new SessionManager(context);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String authorized = "";
        HashMap<String, String> app = mSessionManager.getAPPDetails();
        ...
    }
}

public static class SessionManager {
    private final SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    public SessionManager(Context context){
        mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();  // I wouldn't do that here ; edit when you will really need to and commit afterwards
    }
}
```

`SharedPreferences` is also of the same scope as the app itself so is OK to keep a reference to.
Note that I made the `AsyncTask` class static, this would prevent from unknowingly leaking a reference to its nesting object (most likely an `Activity`).

PS: Java typically doesn't use the underscore prefix naming convention ;)