# Difference between getApplication(), getApplicationContext()... so on

Tags: android

I'm wondering what the difference between all those methods:
`getApplication(), getApplicationContext(), getActivity()` is.
I use it fairly often for toasts and stuff but only know which one to choose because
of the IDE-help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext might help you

Comment: this is the best explanation so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Answer (score 1):

You should rather try to understand what is the difference between [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) and [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). All the 3 concepts are well documented in the Android official documentation.

To be fair, the meaning of context is not so clear from the documentation, so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) is a short explanation and [here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) is a long one