# Google Analytics for Android v4 - Sending Event on BroadcastReceiver

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android, google-analytics-firebase

I've recently started using Google Analytics on my android app. I'd like to know how can I send and Event to GA inside onReceive method of a BroadcastReceiver. It's a SMS receiver and I'd like to tell google every time a tet message arrives.

The problem is that I don't know how can I get the tracker. Inside the activities I use:

```
myTracker = ((Myapplication)getApplication()).getTracker();
```

But I can't use getApplication() inside the onReceive. I've tried using:

```
myTracker = ((Myapplication)context).getTracker();
```

and the app crashes when the SMS arrives.

Thank you everyone! I hope yu can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
myTracker = ((Myapplication)context.getApplicationContext()).getTracker();
```

This ensures that the `Context` you are casting is the Application itself.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it's not recommended to use it as it could depend on manufacturer implementation http://stackoverflow.com/a/6760019/337141

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's a real problem or something developers should worry about