# Access to application class in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle, android-broadcast, android

I want to check internet connection in Broadcast Receiver; And set result (A boolean flag) to a global variable, to use it on whole application, in if conditions; That if internet is disconnected, set a status imageview in main activity, to red image, and if connected, set it to green.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable) topic. But there is no `getApplication()` in Broadcast Receiver; And iI should use `getApplicationContext()` instead.

On another side, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext) topic:

> when writing code in a broadcast receiver, which is not a context but
>   is given a context in its onReceive method, you can only call
>   getApplicationContext(). Which also means that you are not guaranteed
>   to have access to your application in a BroadcastReceiver.

1. What are the concerns?
2. How can I access to my application class in broadcast Receiver?
3. Is there better solution to check internet connection, set global variable and change my status imageview?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can access your `Application` class in `BroadCastReceiver` by using its context,

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
   MyApplication mApplication = ((MyApplication)context.getApplicationContext());
 }
```

Comment: So what is the quote's point? "you are not GUARANTEED to have access to your application in a BroadcastReceiver" ?!

Comment: Ofcourse you does have access to Application class in BroadCastReceiver.

Comment: Is this mean quote is not true? By the way, does my scenario to receive and change network status is correct totally?

Comment: I am never using `getApplication()` to get the instance of Application class and always using `getApplicationContext()` to get instance of Application, so its guaranteed 100%

Comment: Ok, but how can i change a imageview in main activity, when internet connection changed?

Comment: thats a different topic/question that you asked in your question, but still I will just give a hint of having a listener in your Activity which gets fired when Internet comes or goes.

Comment: By listener, do you mean broadcast receiver?

Comment: That currently the object returned by getApplicationContext happens to be the application instance itself is an implementation detail that most certainly is NOT guaranteed by the API.

Comment: To guard against ClassCastExceptions, you can check: `if (context.getApplicationContext() instanceof MyApplication) {`

Comment: @LalitPoptani any comment in response to cumbayah's comment and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext/6760019#6760019

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will help somebody. If using own application class:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App sInstance;

    public static App get() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        sInstance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

Then you can use **App.get()** in your broadcast receiver.
According to onCreate() [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) it will be called before receiver calls.

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.

Comment: Oh yes it helped me. Thanks mate!

Comment: It's not a good approach. Please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45402990/421467

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Have you ever got memory leak discribed in answer you provide? If yes, please tell me the way to reproduce it :)