# What is the difference between getActivity() and getApplicationContext() in android?

Tags: android, networking, android-fragments

When using methods on context, I always get a confusion which one to use and when, namely, getActivity() or getApplicationContext() . Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this down-voted so much?  Seems like a legit question to me.  (Also repeated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext) with much better results.  Maybe the question has been edited...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference btn mContext.get().getApplicationContext() and getActivity()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447762/difference-btn-mcontext-get-getapplicationcontext-and-getactivity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getSystemService()` is a method on `Context`. `Fragment` does not inherit from `Context`. `Activity` does. You can call `getActivity()` on your `Fragment` to obtain an `Activity` on which to call `getSystemService()`.

Comment: @NagabhushanBaddi: Use `Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` because `CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` is static constant in Context class so you need to use class name to access it

Comment: @NagabhushanBaddi: "I tried even getActivity().getSystemService()" -- you can see `getSystemService()` in [the JavaDocs for `Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)).