# Difference between getApplicationContext() and getActivity()

Tags: android

What is the difference between getApplicationContext() and getActivity() and *this* in Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between getActivity() and getApplicationContext() in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385610/what-is-the-difference-between-getactivity-and-getapplicationcontext-in-andr)

Comment: Why don't you Google before asking..??http://stackoverflow.com/a/33447949/6127411

Comment: Refer following link:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and

Answer (score 17):

There is a lot of difference between :

[View.getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29): 
Returns the context the view is currently running in. Usually the currently active Activity.

[Activity.getApplicationContext():](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) 
Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside of). Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the current Activity.

[ContextWrapper.getBaseContext():](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext%28%29) 
If you need access to a Context from within another context, you use a ContextWrapper. The Context referred to from inside that ContextWrapper is accessed via getBaseContext().

Also check :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10641257/4018207
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29

Answer (score 2):

There is huge difference. An android application can have more than one activity, when you say `getApplicationContext()`, it gives you the context of entire application:  [see details :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

However when you say `getActivity()` it just gives you the instance of activity which you are currently in.