# How to get Application from Context

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way I can get application from Context. I noticed that activity and service has getApplication() method but Context does not.

**Background:**

I am using/extending the GCMBaseIntentService and the

```
protected abstract void  onMessage (Context context, Intent intent)
```

gives me a context as a parameter. I would like to get the Application object so I can downcast it to MyApplication and retrieve some variables

Thanks

Comment: (YourApplicationClass)context.getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Context#getApplicationContext` will return your `Application` instance.

Comment: How so? The docs say that it will return "the **context** of the single, global Application object of the current process." The return type is `Context`, not `Application`. `Context` is an ancestor class of `Application`, but how do you know that `getApplicationContext()` will return the `Application` instance? I suspect you may be right, but I'd like to see an authoritative source that agrees.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext which says that `getApplicationContext()` will **not** always return the same object as your `Application` instance.

Comment: Is this even a correct answer? Why is it accepted and upvoted so much?

Comment: I can't find a statement confirming my answer, but at least the Google devs [use this method in AndroidX](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/lifecycle-process/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F&autodive=0%2F#162)

Answer (score 11):

```
val application : Application = context.applicationContext as Application
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer in kotlin:

```
        @BindingAdapter("app:setSelectArea")
        @JvmStatic
        fun setSelectArea(view: ImageView, mContext: ContextX){
            view.setOnClickListener {
                val application = view.context.applicationContext as Application
                val viewModel:KnowledgeViewModel by lazy { KnowledgeViewModel(application) }
                val mKnowledge = Knowledge(
                    "",
                    "abcdefg test",
                    ""
                )
                viewModel.firebaseInsertKnowledge(mKnowledge)
            }
        }
```