# Can't get the unique Android device ID

Tags: java, android

Everyone is talking about this code:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

When I write this, there will be error like:

"The method getContext() is undefined for the type Bridge"

How can I fix that?

Comment: are you writing this in an activity?

Comment: I was writing it in an function.
Looked like that:


    public static String AndroidID() {
    return Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),    Secure.ANDROID_ID);  
    }

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue too,

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using getApplicationContext() instead of getContext()?

```
package de.vogella.android.deviceinfo;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class ShowDeviceInfo extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            String deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            Toast.makeText(this, deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

http://blog.vogella.com/2011/04/11/android-unique-identifier/

These links might help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

[getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)

[Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() , getContext(), and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should pass an instance of `Context` into your `Bridge` class.
To achieve this, you can pass a `Context` to your constructor, or wherever you want.

As you know, every method belongs to some class in Java. So when you call the method not from some object, like you do with `getContext()`, this is equal to calling `this.getContext()`. So you try to call the method from the instance of a class you are operation in now (`Bridge`), which does not have such a method defined. That's why you get the error

> The method getContext() is undefined for the type Bridge

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

It was that my class was not extending `AppCompatActivity` as `getContentResolver()` is a method which resides in that class.