# Get application instance returns null

Tags: android, debugging

I have no ideas, but...

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    public MyApplication() {//for example, here
        instance = this;
    }

     @Override
    public void onCreate() { //or here
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

in my activity

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {//onStart, onCreate, etc 
        MyApplication.getInstance().doSomething();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

And in random moments I have the crash.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.mypackage.myapplication, PID: 17579
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.mypackage.myapplication.MyFragmentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mypackage.myapplication.MyApplication.getInstance().doSomething()' on a null object reference
```

ie MyApplication.getInstance returns null! How do you think, what the... issue?
Using debug in AndroidStudio 2.0

Comment: also I don't know, how to reproduce this issue manually

Comment: Have you defined the application in your manifest?

Comment: yep. this issue comes from case to case

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want application context to perform some operations, I Don't know why you need your own application instance.
Use `getApplicationContext();` to get context

Another solution is to  define your application class in your manifest under application tag

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment below for any further information

Comment: Wow, bro! It seems like you saved my life. Adding app's name to manifest made a deal for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

don't keep the instance as static in application class. 
you can use

```
(MyApplication) getApplicationContext()
```

this will get you your application object.

just dont typecast the activity object to MainApplication class directly.

in case of Test case you can change it to getApplicationContext()

Comment: Don't cast `getApplicationContext()` to `Application`. Use `getApplication()` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext