# getApplicationContext() as a activity to excute runOnUiThread()?

Tags: android, android-context, applicationcontext

```
 ((Activity)getApplicationContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
```

This code is right? I get a trouble to think it!

Comment: no it is not, Application Context is not an activity

Comment: I think so,but I don't know if this code is excuted successfully @tyczj

Comment: it should crash for ClassCastException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runOnUiThread()` it's a method from `Activity` so if you are on an `Activity` you can avoid this : `((Activity)getApplicationContext())`, but if you are on a `Fragment`, you'll need to get the first your `Activity` and then call this method, otherwise you won't be able to call it.

You should change this : `((Activity)getApplicationContext())`

to this :

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
});
```

It can throw you a `ClassCastException` as Blackbelt said in comments.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760019/923441

You should definitely NOT cast getApplicationContext() to Actvity, it is not guaranteed to work and such programming will lead to crashes down the line.