# java.lang.ClassCastException when I try cast Application to MyApplication from a Fragment(Android 6+)

Tags: java, android, classcastexception, android-application-class

I have a fragment which extends **android.app.Fragment**. Inside onCreateView in some case I have **java.lang.ClassCastException** when I try cast Application to my implementation of Application.

```
public class SketchFragment extends android.app.Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,inflate);

        MyApplication application = (MyApplication)  getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        //Previously, I tried to
        //MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()

        }
    }
```

Actually I have this error in <5% of all users(My Crashlytics log say that) only in **Android 6**. **My Crashlytics log below :**

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
>   cannot be cast to com.example.app.MyApplication
>
> ```
>    at com.example.app.ui.activity.main.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:95)
>    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2281)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:983)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1163)
>    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1552)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:487)
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
> ```

My application part from Manifest file:

> <application
>           android:name="**.MyApplication**"
>           android:allowBackup="true"
>           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>           android:label="..."
>           android:largeHeap="true"
>           android:supportsRtl="true"
>           android:theme="@style/AppTheme"   >    </application    >

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: have you looked into this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6760019/588532

Comment: Were you able to figure out the cause - I am getting the same exception for some users in Android 6.0 in my service class. Service.getApplication() no longer casts to <MyApplication>.

Comment: Looks like an android issue but no resolution or acknowledgement yet - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137009