# how safe is to use application class's context in entire android app

Tags: android

I have created one class that is extending Application class and using the static method to expose the contexts as follows. moreover i am using many util methods like checking internet connections e.c.t into this class.

Problem is i am not sure

1. how safe is to use following method to expose the application level context
2. would this create any memory leaks when i will use `App.getAppContext()` method

   ```
   public class App extends Application {        

   private static Context mContext;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
   }

   public static Context getAppContext() {

   return mContext;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Application context everywhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)

Comment: according to that question `Context.getApplicationContext()` can be used but its not available

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)

Comment: It's safe to a certain degree, except `android:process=":remote"` makes a second process, which  results in a second Application instance.