# Cannot cast Application to CustomApplication

Tags: android

I have a `CustomApplication extends Application` class, which is  registered in `AndroidManifest`

```
 <application
    ....
// Please, pay attention that I got this in my Manifest
    android:name=".CustomApplication">
```

And at different part of my application, both some activities and services I do
`getApplication()/getApplicationContext()` then cast it to `CustomApplication` and it crashes in production on a variety of devices/sdk versions(beginning at android 6) due to a class cast exception. `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException`

Example:

```
class CustomApplication extends Application{
...
public static CustomApplication with(Context context) {
       return (CustomApplication) context.getApplicationContext(); //crashes here
   }
}
```

and service example:

```
class CustomService extends IntentService{
...
@Override
rotected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        CustomApplication app = CustomApplication.from(getApplication());
        // tried getApplicationContext() also
}
}
```

and activity example:

```
class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(...){
   CustomApplication app = CustomApplication.with(this);
}
```

What I've tried:

- Tried services with different `process=":process"`
- Tried deep linking with different `launchModes`
- Tried activities with `taskAffinity`
- launching from push notifications
- process cleaning with system tray(on device), ps kill int adb shell

nothing helps me to reproduce an issue on emulator

I don't use `Instant Run` also (never used it)

Please don't provide me with suggests of using `static application context instance`

Comment: A [mcve] would be appreciated

Comment: @cricket_007 if I would be able to reproduce it, I wouldn't ask question here

Comment: Why are you casting your context? `getApplication ()` and `getApplicationContext()` are not the same. getApplicationContext returns the context of the single, global Application object.

Comment: @cricket_007 got 1kk monthly active users on project. That issue happens like ~100 times a day

Comment: @codeFreak https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext

Comment: Is there a specific case why a regular singleton class can't be used?

Comment: @cricket_007 I got DI(Dagger 2) and I got legacy part of an application that can't be used with dagger 2 for now. Anyway, even If I would rewrite everything for a `valid` singletons - I'm still curious about that stuff

Comment: @cricket_007 Cause it crashes in both services and activity.

Comment: Is it crashing specifically on Dagger usage?

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope. I updated issue with an example

Comment: what is that `with()` method supposed to do? It seems useless

Comment: @TimCastelijns it's been done for convenience. You pass your current context there and you get an application instance. You can find out that kind of stuff in Telegram/Actor source codes

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Why does `with()` not just return `this`? without requiring a context as parameter

Comment: @TimCastelijns because I don't hold a static reference of Application context

Comment: @nomag what should I find there?

Comment: I did not mention a static context, nor is it required

Comment: @TimCastelijns I cannot return `this` instance from a static method

Comment: oh yeah I didn't see the static

Comment: @Alex Please read given link for explanation why it can not be cast sometimes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760019/8101621

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a static reference of your `CustomApplication` like below. You don't need to cast in the following way.

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    private static CustomApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        instance = this;
    }

    public static CustomApplication getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then call `CustomApplication.getContext();`

Comment: I'm here to find out why .applicationContext cannot be casted to CustomApplication class. Cause it's going to clarify me a lot of android internal processes

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your custom application in the manifest as follow:

```
<application
    ....
    android:name="my.package.path.CustomApplication"> 

    ... activities ....

 </application>
```

Also, you are getting an instance of a class that extends `Application`, not `Context`, that being said you should call this the following way:

```
CustomApplication customApplication;
customApplication = (CustomApplication)getApplication();
```

What you might have to apply in case you have BroadcastReceiver(No context available) is:

```
customApplication = (CustomApplication)getApplicationContext().getApplication();
```

Comment: I'm just giving you a full example in how you should use it. Try out what I've posted and you will see it will work.

Comment: it's been there for like 4 years already. App in production has 1 million monthly active users

Comment: and why should I do getapplicationContext().getApplication() for intent service?

Comment: Intent service extends service, therefor you don't have a context. When you do `(CustomApplication)getApplication` in an Activity you are basically writing `(CustomApplication)this.getApplication`. Thats why in classes that are not Activities you need to either pass the context, or get the application context, which is the case of an IntentService

Comment: I will, I gotta do a staged rollout on the audience. I'm not capable to reproduce it on any of my devices at any scenario

Comment: And as I mentioned in my question, I tried both `.getApplicationContext()` and `.getApplication()` from service. And they all failed

Comment: I just crashes ~50-100 times a day. So there's a specific scenario during which .getApplication/getApplicationContext does not return a CustomApplication instance. I suppose it to be a vendor specific issue

Comment: It is a possibility. I've worked with a few applications already with thousands of monthly users and never had a problem with the approach I gave you

Comment: But you gave me the same approach I use

Comment: I have my application class registered in manifest, and I do the same class casting of .getApplication as you do. What's the difference?

Comment: the only difference I've found out is you do .getApplicationContext().getApplication() and I asked you to provide me with some links to resources to clarify that for me

Comment: I explained when and why you must call getApplicationContext in a comment above. read it

Comment: But intent Service has context. It is a context. You can examine it both in android SDK and android documentation;
And it has both .getApplication() and .getApplicationContext() methods

Comment: You are correct. I was confusing with BroadcastReceiver, thats where you need to call getApplicationContext.