# Android - Using this or getApplicationContext() in MyApplication class?

Tags: android, android-context, android-application-class

I have created a `MyApplication` class that extends `Application` and have defined it in the manifest.

Within `MyApplication`'s `onCreate()` method, is there any difference between using `this` or `getApplicationContext()` in order to get the application context?

(Presumably, the latter just exists because `Application` is a `Context`, but I just need to be sure.)

Comment: in your application subclass `this` and `getApplicationContext()`   are the same

Comment: @Blackbelt, and that is not always true. `getApplicationContext()` not always returns an instance of the application.

Comment: @VladMatvienko, the documentations disagrees with you

Comment: @Blackbelt, sorry, but looks like you are using non-official Android documentation. Because this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext() `getApplicationContext` returns a `context of the single, global Application object of the current process`, not an application object itself. In most cases they are the same, but not in **all cases**. Reffer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext

Comment: The question was about the `getApplicationContext()` *inside* the `MyApplication` class that extends the `Application` - and there they will be the same.

Comment: Why downvote this question? What's wrong with it? Do some people choose to downvote simply because they know the answer when the asker doesn't?! And if that's the case, then why not downvote every single question you know the answer to rather than leaving an answer - which would actually help, which is what Stack Overflow is meant to be all about, right??

Comment: Or should each question be prefixed with "I've been searching google for hours, but can't find the answer..." ?!

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Did my answer help you ? (I think your question isn't wrong at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `MyApplication` inherit indirectly from the `Context` class (Applicaiton > ContextWrapper > Context). So when you use the reference `this` as Context instance, you are just using the [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) concept.

> is there any difference between using this or getApplicationContext() in order to get the application context?

There is no difference.