# what to use instead of this if the target is not on main.axml

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile

So I'm trying to use an autoCompleteTextView in my project and my problem is that the autoCompleteTextView is not in the *main.axml*, but in the *pager_item.axml* so when I use

```
ArrayAdapter autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, autoCompleteOptions);
```

the build is succesful, but the progrem crash at the start saying 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

when the SetContentView is set to pager_item.axml it works fine, but i dont want to set the content view, because i still need the main.axml.

so my question is what sould i use instead of **this** when my autoCompleteTextView is not on the active layout.

Comment: Hi, by `what sould i use instead of this`, what do you mean? `ArrayAdapter`'s construction method need the `Context` parameter.

Comment: you are seeing it right, the problem is that i dont know what is the context parameter that i sould use

Comment: could you give an example on what is the context parameter?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`LayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to inflate your `pager_item.axml` in your `MainActivity`.

### Example

```
Android.Views.View view;
view=LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.pager_item, this, false);
AutoCompleteTextView autotext=view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.at);
```

### Edit

> could you give an example on what is the context parameter?

There are three kinds of [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) in Android, [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
 and [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Let's see Button's construction method [Button (Context context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html#Button(android.content.Context)), it needs a Context parameter. If you initialize it using `new Button(this);`, in Activity, `this` is Activity, in Service, `this` is Service, in other class, you can use global Context by [getApplication or getApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext).