# Call Application context in Activity

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

I'm trying to call my database (made with Room) from an activity on Android, but it needs the application context, and if I passed "application : Application" in the constructor of my Activity, the build crash and tell me :

> java.lang.Class<com.exemple.instabus.PhotoActivity> has no zero argument constructor

Here is my code :

```
class PhotoActivity(application: Application) : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val pictureDao = PictureDatabase.getDatabase(app)

//Some code ....
```

I need a context, i've tried to pass "this" but i got another error

Can someone give me some help please, I'm a beginner in this technology

EDIT:

Here is my database class, just to show you why I need an Application Context

```
@Database(entities = [Picture::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class PictureDatabase : RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun pictureDao() : PictureDao

     companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE : PictureDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): PictureDatabase {
            if(INSTANCE == null){
                synchronized(this){
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.applicationContext,
                            PictureDatabase::class.java,
                            "pictures.db"
                    ).build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext

Comment: Thank you @Reza for this link to another question, I learn something, but not enough to solve my problem..

Comment: well my friend remove application: Application from activity consructor. usually activities and fragments should have empty constructor because android instantiates them for us and we are not responsible for creating them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity is something we do declare in the manifest and then start them using `intent`, However, the creation of an instance of an activity is done by the `system` and not by us. An instance is created using `constructor`, but if it is us then we can have any number of overloaded constructors. But the system needs only one constructor which should be a zero parameter constructor and it should be public.

So your activity signature

```
class PhotoActivity(application: Application) : AppCompatActivity() {
```

should be changed to

```
class PhotoActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
```

To call the `fun getDatabase(context: Context): PictureDatabase` you can pass `this` from the `activity`. Activity is an indirect child of `Context`.

You can do it in the following ways,

1. `private val pictureDao by lazy{  PictureDatabase.getDatabase(this) }`
2. `private lateinit var pictureDao:PictureDatabase`
   then in `onCreate()` initialize it

```
final override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)
        PictureDatabase.getDatabase(this)
        //your logic goes here
   }
```

Comment: I understand how it works now, many thanks for this answer, and it works !

Answer (score 1):

First create a ViewModel, and inside the ViewModel you can access the your Dao, pictureDao.

```
 class PictureViewModel(application: Application) : 
   AndroidViewModel(application) {


     val pictureDao: PictureDao

     init {
         pictureDao = 
        PictureDatabase.getDatabase(application).pictureDao()
   
         }



      }
```

Then in your activity, initialize the ViewModel. And access your Dao.

```
 class PhotoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private lateinit var pictureViewModel: PictureViewModel

 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo)

    pictureViewModel = 
   ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PictureViewModel::class.java)

   //You can now access your Dao class here:
   val pictureDao = pictureViewModel.pictureDao




    
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass `Application` to the constructor. You should pass `applicationContext` to `getDatabase()`, like `private val pictureDao = PictureDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext)`

Comment: I have a type mismatch error : Application is expected

Comment: I'll edit my post to let you see why I need Application context