# getSystemService() from Application Context

Tags: android

I want to get ConnectivityManager from Application Context.

But I'm not sure It will be same when get from Activity Context.

Where can I find a clue?

I can't find implementation of Application#getSystemService()..

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine.  The main things that are different in the Activity context are resources, which can be effected by the theme of the activity, the orientation, etc.  System services should be the same across the app, they represent some external service wrapper managed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

`getSystemService` is defined in `Context` class and every class which is child of `Context` can access this method directly . That includes `Application`, `Activity` , `Service` .

```
getApplication().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Both are valid . also u might want to check [getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)