# Send notifications only when activity is in background

Tags: android

I need a way to determine whether ativity active or in the background. I have a service which notifies user, but I want to do it only when activity is inactive.
I might use global variables, set them in onStop() for example, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you try to do it with [ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()) took the idea directly from [How to determine if one of my activities is in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314969/how-to-determine-if-one-of-my-activities-is-in-the-foreground)