# SharedPreferences obtained in BroadcastReceiver are stale

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm having trouble accessing my preferences from a `BroadcastReceiver`. I'm using the following code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = MyReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                context.getApplicationContext());
        Log.d(TAG, sharedPreferences.getAll().toString());
    }
}
```

This code always prints stale preferences. When I go to my PreferenceActivity, change settings and then fire an event that triggers the above `BroadcastReceiver` it always prints old values for the preferences.

I also added the same code to my main activity and it always prints the correct settings.

What is going on here? Are the settings being cached? Is there a way to force a reload from my `BroadcastReceiver` ?

Comment: What happens when you try to print just one preference? Does it change when you change it?

Comment: Nope. Same thing. Old values.

Comment: the same question (and answer) has been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098981/sharedpreferences-in-broadcastreceiver-seems-to-not-update

Answer (score 0):

It seems my problem is described in [SharedPreferences in BroadcastReceiver seems to not update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098981/sharedpreferences-in-broadcastreceiver-seems-to-not-update)

My BroadcastReceiver is started from a `Service` that looks like:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:process=":remote">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.MyService"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Removing the `android:process=":remote"` made my problem go away. Though I am not sure if this is the right thing to do for my application. I kind of depend on this service being detached from the main app as it needs to be started at boot time.