# Start activity that is on the foreground

Tags: android

Is there a way to know if the activity I want to start, is already the activity on the foreground?

Comment: See that question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314969/how-to-determine-if-one-of-my-activities-is-in-the-foreground

Comment: You could have a look at launchModes. With the proper launchMode, you can prevent the device from starting more than one instance of your Activity, if that is what you want. Be careful when you use it, because in some launchmodes, onActivityResult doesn't work the way you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of `Activity` in foreground with `ActivityManager`. Here is the code:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfos = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
String foreGroundActivityName = runningTaskInfos.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().toString();
```

You can then compare the name with your `Activity`. And make sure you add  `android.permission.GET_TASKS` permission in manifest file.