# Detecting the current activity in focus

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a program that can send input to a running application. But if sometimes any erroneous input is given the program exits or loses focus. I just want to know if I can detect the current activity that is on focus and compare it with my programs activity to learn whether the desired program lost focus or not.
The program i am testing is a third party application. So i cannot write the program myself. All i need to know is to learn the current running activity with focus. 
The tool I am using to send commands is written in ruby and java. Do you have any java program to query about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this, it it helps you in any way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314969/how-to-determine-if-one-of-my-activities-is-in-the-foreground

Comment: I have seen that lik before. But as i said the application I am quering is not my own. i cannot put my own code in onResume or onPause.