# Android - How to check my app is open when receive a push-notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I need best solution. When I received a push notification, I want to know if my app is open or not, because if my application is open when the user onClick the notification I want to call specific method, but if the application is close I want to open the application.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is way to check if one of your activity is in Foreground. May be you should check this [How to determine if one of my activities is in the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314969/how-to-determine-if-one-of-my-activities-is-in-the-foreground)

Answer (score -1):

```
//Use this method to check your app is running or not
public boolean isAppRunning(){
        String packageName="Your package name";
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfoslist = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(int i = 0; i < procInfoslist.size(); i++)
        {
            if(procInfoslist.get(i).processName.equals(packageName))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

`
//Use this method to check any activity is running or not

public boolean isActivityRunning(Context ctx) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
            if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! please could you post some description about your answer.  Thank you.