# SendBroadcast if Activity or Notification

Tags: android

I have an application that downloads data in a background service and I want to be able to update an activity UI if they are currently running the application or trigger a Notification if they are not.

How do I know if the application is currently in the foreground?

I could register a BroadcastReceiver inner class in the activity and trigger this if its in the foreground otherwise uses notification but I don't know how I can check what action to take.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: This is similar to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282435/inform-activity-from-a-broadcastreceiver-only-if-it-is-in-the-foreground

Answer (score 3):

Use an ordered broadcast, with the activity implementing a high-priority `BroadcastReceiver` and a separate low-priority `BroadcastReceiver` to raise the `Notification`. I have a [blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) covering this specific topic.