# Scroll ListView on Intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I got a complicated problem involving a ListView and some Intents on Android:

I have a `ListActivity` which contains many items. From another Activity, lets call it `CallingActivity`, I want to launch this `ListActivity` and scroll to a specific item. In the `ListActivity` some other Activites can be launched, lets call them `AnotherActivity`.

My current implementation is to store the item to which the ListActivity should scoll in the intent and then use the following code in the `onStart()` method.

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(EXTRA_EVENTNR)) {
        int p = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(EXTRA_EVENTNR);
        getListView().clearFocus();
        getListView().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getListView().setSelection(p);
            }
        });
    }
```

This solution has a huge drawback:

Suppose the following call-sequence:

1. `CallingActivity` launches `ListActivity` with Intent `[EVENTNR=123]`
2. `ListActivity` recieves the intent and scrolls to the right position.
3. User continues to read and scrolls further down.
4. `AnotherActivity` is launched from `ListActivity`
5. The User presses the Back-Button
6. The old intent (from 1.) is still present and gets passed again in `onStart` of the `ListActivity`.
7. `ListActivity` scrolls to the same position again (same as in 2.)
8. **Scrolling of the User from 3. is lost**

I think a Intent is the wrong solution for carrying the scroll-information. Intents are more for the contents of a activity and not for its display.

Is there another solution for passing the scrolling information which only gets applied once? Did I miss something?

Comment: It could be possible using BroadcastReceivers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282435/inform-activity-from-a-broadcastreceiver-only-if-it-is-in-the-foreground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do `getIntent().removeExtra()` to remove your extra data?

On the other hand it might be that putting the info into the `Intent` is an unnesessary complication as you don't really need an Intent for that. 
Can it be a plain java object to store that info with API to set and reset it?

Comment: Thanks for the `removeExtra` hint. Anyway, could you explain what do you mean by `API to set and reset`? How can I send the value where to scroll from `CallingActivity` to `ListActivity?

Comment: Oh, I just thought what is causing troubles is the Intent because it's always there. So I just meant maybe create a plain Java class like ScrollInfo with methods set(int pos) and clear() and pass that instead of Intent. Same as removeExtra() though...