# How get Activity form BroadcastReceiver in onReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I define BroadcastReceiver in an application manifest and the receiver receives events in onReceive as expected. However I do not create the receiver class so I can't pass any information about my activity which the receiver is supposed to control. Context parameter gives me only application context and no any activity reference. So what is right way to make communication between application activities and broadcast receiver?

Comment: y u need activity if u can say that will b helpful ?

Comment: this is the right answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a little twisted but I found it here as well
[Inform Activity from a BroadcastReceiver ONLY if it is in the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282435/inform-activity-from-a-broadcastreceiver-only-if-it-is-in-the-foreground)
It seems working. Please close the question then.

Answer (score -2):

You can communicate broadcast to activity from this:-

```
   Intent intent=new Intent(context,YourActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I do not need to start an activity, I need to communicate with an existing one.