# Sending data from background service to activity which is current in background

Tags: c#, android

Consider the scenario when user opens app and goes straight **activity A**. `OnCreate` method creates service which runs in the background.

```
this.StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(MyService)));
```

This service runs independently from activity, so if the user closes or destroys app, service still be running.

In **activity A** I register couple receivers via `RegisterReceiver`, so when something happens in my background service I update **activity A** via sending broadcast.

The problem I am facing is when user goes from **activity A** to **activity B**. At this time service is sending broadcast that something needs to be changed on **activity A**, but as it is not in a foreground, I will not will be updated via receiver. So when user goes back from **activity A** to **activity B**, user sees old data. And service does these updates in irregular intervals.

What is the proper way to update activity which was in background and then goes to foreground? What is the appropriate way to get hold of service reference or data in activity?

As I understand if I use binded services, it will be destroyed when app is killed. And I don't want that. All tutorials only shows how to update activity which is in foreground.

I'm just getting to know android, so maybe I am missing some obvious small detail.

Comment: you can send broadcast to your activity only when it is in foreground that will solve your problem

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman but how do I ask for these updates? Service is sending most recent data in broadcasts at irregular intervals - next update might be after 5mins, so I don't want to user to relay data until next update

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282435/inform-activity-from-a-broadcastreceiver-only-if-it-is-in-the-foreground

Answer (score 0):

1. You can persist your data in database or file
2. You can restart service to fetch updated data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Context#sendStickyBroadcast`. It is deprecated, but still working. Your activity will get such broadcast when it goes foreground. Don't forget `Context#removeStickyBroadcast` after getting it.